# What does the phrase "human experience" mean in the context of Hegelian philosophy?

Tags: hegel

The following is an extract from an introductory paragraph on Hegel on Spark Notes (https://www.sparknotes.com/philosophy/hegel/context/):

> Georg Wilhelm Friedrich Hegel was born in 1770 in Stuttgart, Wurttemberg, which was then one of numerous autonomous German principalities that would become the German state in 1871. His eventual preoccupation with the link between human experience and history can be traced to the uncertainties of the time and place in which he lived.

How are "human experience" and "history" different terms?

I have just begun with philosophy, and Hegel almost makes me regret choosing the subject.

Comment: Hegel is not a good place to begin with philosophy, he only grows on you after much exposure. "Human experience" is not his term, what they mean is that Hegel was the first to systematically explore how the way people perceive themselves and the world, their *Geist* (spirit), depends on the historical development of culture they belong to. It is a bit mythologized in his own presentation, as he was an idealist. In particular, this *Geist* is a self-standing entity that evolves through history by way of what Hegel calls *dialectic*.

Comment: Thanks @Conifold